# How to run Maven project using simple java command

Tags: java, maven

I know I can use `mvn exec:java ...` to run my Maven project. But since I want to learn more about Java, I'm trying to run my project with the `java` command. Here is my project structure:

```
pom.xml
src/
    main/java/com/company/prod/
        Obj.java
        Main.java
target/
    classes/com/company/prod/
        Obj.class
        Main.class
```

I'm trying to run Main by executing `java -cp target/classes/com/company/prod target/classes/com/company/prod/Main`. But I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: target.classes.com.company.prod.Main`.

I also tried to `cd` into the `target/classes/com/company/prod/` directory and run `java -cp . Main` but then I got `Error: Could not find or load main class Main Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/company/prod/Main (wrong name: Main)`.

Why is this not working?

Comment: You should be using `java -cp target/classes com.company.prod.Main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
java -cp target/classes com.company.prod.Main
```

The class path ends just before the package directories start.

Comment: That worked, only now, it can't find my maven dependencies. So I guess I need to add these dependencies to my classpath manually.

Comment: Yes. All dependencies must be reachable via the class path.

Answer (score 0):

Mentioned Main class in POM by

```
<mainClass>src.main.java.org.jis.Main</mainClass>
```

Create executable jar file and run command java -jar your_jar_name.jar